# つく meaning in キズがつきやすい?

Tags: meaning

the verb つく has a lot of vague definitions and, in this sentence, it's not even written in kanji so finding the meaning would be more difficult.
I searched in jisho.org and am confused to choose the most suitable meaning for this sentence.

https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you found so far via a web / dictionary search? [Generally questions here need to show some prior research effort.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: 2番に "to scar" ってあるやん・・

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, つく is an intransitive verb that means one thing, "to attach (to something)". The subject can be a small physical object:

- 窓に水滴がつく
- グラスに指紋がつく
- 地面に足跡がつく

...or an intangible physical attribute:

- 服に臭いがつく
- 床に汚れがつく
- 葉に色がつく
- 車にスピードがつく
- 木に火がつく

...or a person:

- 門に見張りがつく
- 患者に看護婦がつく

...or even a characteristic/trait:

- 計画に文句がつく
- 体に精力がつく
- 結果に差がつく

How these are naturally translated to English is a different question, and you have manage them on a case by case basis. You have to memorize common expressions one by one.

- あの木に火がついている。 That tree is on fire.
- スピードがついた車 a car that is going fast

体に傷がつく literally means "a scar attaches to one's body", which may seem strange, but that's how Japanese people say "to be scarred" or "to get a scratch" naturally.